# Does WFS-T with Qgiscloud still work?

Tags: qgis, wfs-t, qgis-cloud

I am using QGIS 2.18.0 on win 7.
Found out about this great tutorial:

http://blog.sourcepole.ch/2014/09/02/share-and-manage-your-data-with-qgis-cloud-and-wfs-t/

Does this still work? I am expecting that after publishing, anyone can alter the data?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, WFS-T still works. When you publish your data based on QGIS Cloud Free, everyone can alter your data without any limitation. With QGIS Cloud Pro you can establish limited access and you have full access control.